# Parameter annotations of spring mvc are not inherited

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a interface for spring-mvc 3.1 controllers that looks like

```
  public interface RestCRUDOperations<T> {
         @RequestMapping(value = "/{id:\\d+}", 
                         method = RequestMethod.GET, 
                         produces = "application/json")
         public  ResponseEntity<T> getById(@PathVariable("id") String sourcId);
         //other code omitted
  }
```

What i observed was, in implementating classes the @RequestMapping annotation was still having effect (without me having to copy that over the method implementation) but the @PathVariable weren't having effect , until i copy paste the annotation at corresponding place before the parameter. Does anybody know if there is a way around this ? And/or spring acknowledges this as a bug it intends to fix or something ??

EDIT :-
One ugly way could be to have an abstract class translating methods i.e `public abstract class RESTAdapter implements  RestCRUDOperations` that provides final implementation to these methods and delegates to 2 abstract methods and this abstract class is what the controllers extend. 
 I wanted something automatic.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue on the tracker now .. see https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14526

Answer (score 0):

All annotations that I have seen pretty much work the same. The reason is, the code that scans for them only examines the lowest level child in the hierarchy.

As a workaround, I recommend writing a protected wrapper method in a base class. You can then use it from either the base class, which implements this interface, or the derived class. This is similar to your suggestion.

Lastly, as a bit of friendly advice, it is probably a bad idea to be extending other Controller classes from a purely structural point of view. You will almost always regret it.

Comment: This works fine in Jersey and the @RequestMapping annotations on the interface works fine in Spring MVC.  This seems like a pretty arbitrary thing to not work.